# Aurelia | json parse uncaughtable exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, aurelia

So i am trying to make this post request, following aurelia docs:
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/3

And this is the request:

```
 httpClient.configure(config => {
        config
            .withBaseUrl(baseUrl)
    });
this.client = httpClient;
this.client.fetch(`/api/Register/${userName}`, {
            method: "post",
            body: json(loginInformation),
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }) .then(response => this.safelyParseJSON(response))
            .then(data => this.setup(data));
```

where safetyParseJSON is:

```
    safelyParseJSON(response) {
        var parsed
            try {
                parsed = response.json();
            } catch (e) {
            }

        return parsed 
    }
```

but i keep receiving this error:

> "uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Anyone have any idea on what am i doing wrong?

Note:
I am receiving this error only when receiving 404 / 500 from the server, if the results are ok, this works.

Note2: that i am wrapping this function inside try-catch but this still doesn't work, it doesn't catch the exception.

Note3: I have tried to replace this line:

```
parsed = response.json();
```

with this line:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(response);
```

But than the response is always undefined.

Comment: What does the json that's being returned look like? Check your network tab in your dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Jeremy Danyow answer, with a small change:

```
.then(response => {
 if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {
   return response.json().then(data => this.setup(data));
 }
 return Promise.reject(response.text());
});
```

adding the response.status check was necessary in my case as response.ok was true for status code 204 (No content) aswell.

Comment: I would personally not throw any error on a 204 response status, that's usually a DELETE method and not a bad response but a good one containing no information.

Answer (score 2):

check the response's status prior to calling `.json()`:

```js
.then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json().then(data => this.setup(data));
  }
  return Promise.reject(response.text());
});
```